# What is the right way to handle permalinks when the page depends on the session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http

Here's the situation: I've got an application where you begin at a screen showing a list of countries.  You choose a country, and this becomes the ambient country that the application uses until you change it.  This ambient country is stored in the Session so the application doesn't have to pass around a CountryId in every single url.  But I also want to support permalinks to country specific content, so I guess there needs to be a "Get Permalink" button, which creates a permalink that **does** contain the CountryId, because it obviously has to work independent of the current session.

Here's the question: My understanding is that because selecting a country changes the session state, one should only do it via POST.  But then if the user comes in via GET with a permalink containing, e.g. CountryId=123, what should happen?  Should the page update the Session with country 123?  In this case, it would be breaking the rule that you can change the session ONLY via POST.  But if it *doesn't* change the session, then all the code that relies on the session won't work, and I'd have to have code redundant ways to generate the page.

**OR**, should the page have some sort of mechanism for saying "use the session value, but override with any query string value if there is one (and don't modify the session at all)?

**OR**, am I misunderstanding the POST rule entirely?

Comment: I'm not really a fan of using Session to store these sorts of details. What is wrong with using the query/string or making it part of the route?

Comment: I'm not sure anything is wrong with it, but I thought one of the goals of MVC routing was to have pretty links like /controller/index/3, instead of /index?id=3.  Somewhat less trivial is that I have a number of these ambient settings, so the query string could get kind of long.

Comment: About the routing, it sounds reasonable, but I guess I'm not sure how this should be done.  Are you saying take a half dozen ambient settings and pack them into a route like controller/index/3/123/42/984/14/1252, and unpack these in every action method?  That seems like it would be very hard to follow, and would require a lot of duplication in the action methods.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: How about adding the country to the route but with a "pretty" value (i.e. as indicated here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) so that your route looks like /country/controller/action ?

Comment: @Hector: the countries are actually user defined, per business rules, so that won't work.  But the real question is whether it's a good idea to have routes with one part for every (possibly optional) parameter.

Comment: @Joshua Frank: It's hard to tell without knowing much about your project, but out of box it gives a bad smell. Can you force the URLs  to always have a country?

Comment: @Hector: Why does that smell worse than the usual MVC situation where you have /controller/index/123, where 123 is a meaningless database id?  It so happens that I'm dealing with countries here, but the same question would apply if I were using domain specific business objects with no standardized ISO names.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank I think Darin nailed it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real issue here is the fact that you are using a Session. You cannot provide permalinks because the data that you have stored in the session might have expired when the user follows this links later. So you must somehow persist this data into a more durable datastore when someone requests you to generate a permalink. So when a user asks for a permalink you will go ahead and persist all those search criteria that were used to perform the search into your data store and obtain an unique id that will allow you to fetch them later. Then give the user the following permalink: `/controller/search/id` where the id represents the unique identifier tat will allow you to fetch the criteria from your data store, perform the search and reconstruct the page as it was.

Comment: I didn't really specify it, but the way that I'm using the Session is this: User selects the country and I fetch the Country object from the db and put that in the Session.  That object would indeed expire with the Session, but I could generate a permalink that appended the CountryId to the url, and then re-fetch the Country object when someone navigates to the url.  But I'm starting to think that this is fighting the stateless paradigm and thus trouble.  I'm just not sure what the alternative is, other than having ALL url's in the app contain ALL state info, which also seems messy.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank, yes using a Session is definitely fighting against the stateless nature of the web. Personally the first thing I do when I start a new ASP.NET application is to disable the Session in web.config to ensure that no developer does the mistake of using it. So having a country id to your urls would make sense. It would allow  you to fetch the original country object from the datastore.

Comment: Since asking my question, I have fully accepted that this kind of data shouldn't live in the Session.  But where should it live then?  Say I have many of these kinds of State objects (current country, current foo mode, current bar mode, etc...).  Do I rig up *every single* link in the application with those state parameters controller/action/CountryId=123&foo=xyz&bar=abc&... ?  That seems kind of messy, but I can't see another way without using the session.

Comment: Also, what about the current *user*?  How do you handle that without storing something in the session?  If you used some massive authentication token in the url, then the urls would be *really* messy, and you still couldn't pass them around to other users.

Comment: You use your data store to persist them as if they were standard entities. So you don't have messy urls containing all those properties. A single id allowing you to retrieve the original object from your data store is sufficient. As far as the current user is concerned personally I put commonly needed profile information into the userData part of the authentication cookie so that it is available on each request and so that I don't need to perform additional queries to the data store to fetch it since it will be needed on every request. Also to limit the queries you should use caching.

Comment: Accepting this for the answer and all the helpful follow up comments.  Thanks!